# Adjust Accordion To Allow Current Content Hidding

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a custom accordion script that I'm trying to adapt for another site. I need to be able to close a `div` after opening it, but I can't figure out how to modify it to do so.

Here's my script:

```
$(".accordionHidden").hide();

// Bind to Button click Event //
$("a.accordionHeading").bind("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Set New Target from Button data-target Attribute //
    var $target = $("."+$(this).data("target"));

    // Prevent Slide Up / Down of Current Content //
    if ($(".accordionHidden:visible").get(0) != $target.get(0)){

        // Slide Up Content if Visible //
        if ($(".accordionHidden:visible").length){
            $(".accordionHidden").filter(":visible").slideUp("fast", function(){
                $target.slideDown("fast");
            });
        }
        else {
            $target.slideDown("fast");
        }
    }
});
```

I also need to able to have multiple items open at once, not sure if this script can do this at the moment.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7W2je/2/ (added second accordion, need to have two (or more) open at once)

Comment: should we guess what is the markup?

Comment: Mark up is extremely complex so I didn't really want to post 1000 lines of code here...I'll update with a link to a live demo, although it should be clear from the classes named in the script.

Comment: how can a basic accordion html tree be that complicated? Without seeing basic markup makes for a lot of blind guessing to write simple traverses. Post a demo

Comment: Sorry, it's not that the accordion is complicated, it's the site that's it's being implemented on. I made a simple example on JSFiddle, see original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `slideToggle()` method:

```
$(".accordionHidden").hide();

// Bind to Button click Event //
$("a.accordionHeading").bind("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Set New Target from Button data-target Attribute //
    $("."+$(this).data("target")).slideToggle();
    if ($("a.accordionHeading").text() == 'Maximize') {
       $("a.accordionHeading").text("Show Less Info");
       $("a.accordionHeading").removeClass("minimize").addClass('maximize');
    } else {
        $("a.accordionHeading").addClass("minimize").removeClass('maximize').text('Maximize');
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7W2je/4/

Comment: Close, but the text/class changes don't work as expected and I'm having trouble getting it figured out. I used to think I was pretty good with jQuery before trying anything with accordions, makes no sense to me lol.

Comment: Unfortunately the site's under NDA so I can't just post the code...With multiple accordions on the same page, it's changing every buttons name instead of the clicked ones. Also, the classes seem to get swapped somehow (so when it's maximized, the button's getting `.minimize`, and when it's minimized, the button's getting `.maximize`.)

Comment: Classes still getting swapped, text still oppisite. You can see it in the JSFiddle you linked to. When you click on the button, it's getting  the Maximize text instead of the "Show Less Info" text, and then when you minimize it, it's getting the "Show Less Info" text. Needs to be the other way around, default: Maximize, Expand: Show Less Info, Un-expand: Maximize. It did fix the changing every other button though.